# SSL handshake failed while trying to launch pulse secure VPN

Tags: 14.04, networking, vpn, ssl

After a recent update, I am unable to launch pulse secure VPN from my laptop with 14.04 Ubuntu (64 bit). While I try to launch the UI, I get the message

```
Unable to load page
Problem occurred while loading the URL *************
SSL handshake failed
```

Before the update, I had no such issues. Even now, I can use other vpn (cisco anyconnect) successfully or open web pages.

Any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a support question about a commercial product. Please contact the vendor support instead, that's what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL handshake usually fails when your computer can contact the server, but the server's ssl certificate is not trusted. Try updating to the latest trusted certificate list.

```
cd /etc/ssl/certs
sudo wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

If your vpn uses a self signed certificate, then place its pem file here as well.

Detailed instructions for setting up trusted certificates can be found at Pulse Secures knowledge base:
https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB40278